Html formatted table export to excel
I have table that has superscript tag <td>System Architect<sup>5</sup></td>. I need to export the html formatted table with bold superscript and underlined into excel file keeping the style. I have a handler that will take in the table and make a DataTable but I am not sure how to make the Excel XML <r> tag. Can epplus do this?
HTML Formatted
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect<sup>5</sup></td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Excel formatted
<r><t xml:space="preserve">System Architect</t></r>
<r><rPr><vertAlign val="superscript"/></rPr><t>5</t></r>

Code
using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    pack.SaveAs(ms);
    ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
}


What's the actual problem? EPPLus already converted the datatable into an Excel sheet. There's no need to access low-level XML tags. Excel isn't HTML though and will treat HTML content as just text.

I dont want the excel putout to be HTML content text.

There's no HTML content in Excel, there's only Rich Text Format. You can't make the product do something it wasn't built to do. No amount of XML maniluplation will change this. Cells have a RichText property that can be used to set rich text values just as they have Text to set text values.

Correct there is not html in excel that is why I need to convert it to Excel XML <r> tag so it will keep the formatting

Besides, the XML you posted is NOT HTML. Excel, the application, parsed the HTML markup you provided and converted it. That's a feature of the application, not the Excel format. Excel itself only understands a subset of HTML. That conversion is not something that can be done in general either, because HTML is very complicated, especially once styles and stylesheets get involved. Web apps rarely use raw td for layout or sup transformations. They use stylesheets.

why I need to convert it to that's not a conversion, nor is the r tag what you need. In fact, the most important conversion is sup to vertAlign val="superscript". This is full parsing of the HTML code and re-rendering using completely different markup. That's something that should be done before you  try to create the Excel sheet. Ideally, the data shouldn't be in HTML form at all. What are you trying to convert to Excel anyway?

How would I re-rendering using different markup for excel?

this is a sample of the data https://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/3dvf1x9o/5/

What's the original data? The HTML table is how you expect the data should look like. .LoadFromDataTable(table, c =>{c.PrintHeaders = true;c.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium15;}); can generate a themed table with headers and alternating rows, in any location in a sheet, so there's no reason to use HTML. The only thing that needs special processing is the <sup>5</sup> part and even that could be replaced with the Unicode ⁵ character (Superscript 5)

the data stored in the database is html formatted

the  information needs to be passed to some type of  preprocessing, where we can detect it and then modify that data accordingly
